# When changing form background color I'm getting the indexer is read only error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, darkmode

I am trying to make a dark mode for my Windows forms app but am getting and error. Never set any property of my form to read only neither can I find and option to set it to read only

```
public void TemniNacin()
        {
            LetalskaDruzba.DefaultBackColor = Color.Black;
            foreach (var textboxi in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                textboxi.BackColor= Color.Black;
                textboxi.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

error is happening in the 3rd line

Comment: Of course you get that error message. You're trying to set a read-only property. Did you actually mean to set the `DefaultBackColor`? I'm guessing not.

Comment: which line is giving error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Control.DefaultBackColor Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.defaultbackcolor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is declared as

```cs
public static System.Drawing.Color DefaultBackColor { get; }
```

I.e., it is a read-only property.

You can see this if you hover your mouse-cursor over the property. Visual Studio will then show you this declaration in a tool-tip:

[image]

You can assign this color to the form instance instead:

```cs
BackColor = Color.Black;
```

I assume that this code is inside a `Form` and that `LetalskaDruzba` is the form name. Then you can access the properties, fields and methods of this form directly. No need to prepend it a `this.` as in `this.BackColor = Color.Black;`.